# How to handle C++ container object efficiently?

Tags: c++, performance, copy

Assume I have big multi-level vector. 
(This is just an example for multiple-level contained object tree)

```
vector<vector<vector<int>>> vec1 = getBigVector();
```

If I need to pass an element, I think it will cause kind of copying.

```
vector<vector<int>> vec2 = vec1[2];
vector<vector<int>> vec3 = vec1[3];
```

Doesn't look really efficient than referencing. As far as I know C++ is usually chosen for its efficiency, and I heard C++ is designed to prefer value type object. But, is it still true for containers with many elements? How about container contains another containers?

Is there any hidden secret which can make the operation efficient? Or should I just reference it instead of copying it?

**Update**

Whole object tree needs frequent mutation. And even the tree itself needs to be mutated.

Comment: smart pointers perhaps?

Comment: Unless you need a modifiable copy of that element, a const reference would probably do you wonders for performance. Frankly if those vectors gain even moderately respectable sizes you'd be crazy *not* to.

Comment: If you just want a reference to the elements in the big vector, then do just that -- use a reference to the elements. If you want to put the elements somewhere else, then you have three choices -- you could copy the elements to the new location, you could move the elements to the new location, or you could change your design so that the big vector contains `shared_ptr`s, and share the elements between the big vector and the new location.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, yes, use references instead of copies. If you don't *need* to copy a whole object (if a reference would do just as well), use a reference.

However, sometimes you just want to move or rename an existing object. For that sort of case, you can use the `std::move` function (new in C++11), which basically tells the STL that it's okay to junk the old object if that helps to create the new one faster.

Examples:

```
vector<vector<int>> vec2 = vec1[2];
```

means "create a whole new object, so now there are two objects." This is very slow.

```
vector<vector<int>> &vec2 = vec1[2];
```

means "there is still only one object, but now there are two references to it." This is the fastest option.

```
vector<vector<int>> vec2 = std::move(vec1[2]);  // C++11
```

means "there are two objects, but `vec2` stole the innards of `vec1[2]`, so `vec1[2]` is just an empty husk." This is also generally a pretty fast operation, although not as fast as just creating a reference, of course. It is an error to try to do anything with `vec1[2]` after it has been `std::move`d out of; the only thing you can legally do is call its destructor.

For more information on C++11's `std::move`, Google "rvalue references".